# UWP capture video for fixed duration

Tags: c#, uwp, capture

How can I make a function that captures video for a fixed duration synchronously and returns the video file? I have the following code. The problem is sometimes the while loop never breaks because the line *done_taking_video = true* never gets executed. It is strange.

```
    public StorageFile TakeVideoToFile(int duration_in_ms)
    {

           StorageFile file = foldertosave.CreateFileAsync(filename).AsTask().Result;
           MediaCapture media = new MediaCapture();
           media.InitializeAsync().AsTask().Wait();
           media.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(videoFormat, file).AsTask().Wait();

            System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ => {
                media.StopRecordAsync().AsTask().Wait();
                done_taking_video = true;
            }, null, duration_in_ms, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

            while (!done_taking_video)
            {

            }

            return file;

    }
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why does this need to be done synchronously?

Comment: It is easier to control. I am running this on IoT core. I have a thread that monitors a GPIO pin (connected to a motion detector). Whenever there is motion, I want the camera to capture video for a fixed duration and then upload the video file to an FTP server.